# Python3.8 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, python-3.8

I am trying to install Python3.8 on Ubuntu 14.04, I get this error:

> E: Unable to locate package python3.8 E: Couldn't find any package by
> regex 'python3.8'

Is it even possible to have python3.8 on Ubuntu that is that old? If it is possible, please tell me how.

EDIT

When installing from source ( I followed that [instruction)](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-8-on-ubuntu-18-04/#installing-python-38-on-ubuntu-from-source)
I get this error:

> Fatal Python error: _PySys_InitCore: can't initialize sys module
> Python runtime state: preinitialized
>
> Current thread 0x00002ab78e1b3740 (most recent call first):  generate-posix-vars failed make: *** [pybuilddir.txt] Error 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative solution could be to compile python statically on a newer system. Then such binaries can be transferred to the target system.

Compilation tested on vanilla Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
$ sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev \
libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev libffi-dev zlib1g-dev
$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.6/Python-3.8.6.tgz
$ tar xzf Python-3.8.6.tgz
$ cd Python-3.8.6
$ ./configure LDFLAGS="-static" --disable-shared
$ make LDFLAGS="-static" LINKFORSHARED=" "
....
$ cd ..
$ zip -r Python-3.8.6.zip Python-3.8.6
```

Transfer Python-3.8.6.zip to target sysytem

```
$ unzip Python-3.8.6.zip
$ cd Python-3.8.6
$ ./python
```

Of course you would have to do

> make install

or clean this folder, that's your choice.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, as long as you are not using any kind of dockerization/paravirtualization, simple:

> sudo snap install python38

should work.

Comment: Not for Ubuntu 14.04: ```error: system does not fully support snapd: you need to reboot into a 4.4 kernel to start using
       snapd```

Answer (score 0):

I built python from source directly on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine, almost as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64357580/12315778)
This is what I did:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
$ sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev \
libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev libffi-dev zlib1g-dev

$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.6/Python-3.8.6.tgz
$ tar xzf Python-3.8.6.tgz
$ cd Python-3.8.6
$ ./configure
$ make -j
$ make install
```

And it worked for me just fine